# HashSet not returning expected output

Tags: java, set, hashset

I want to store unique lists, so I am using HashSet. But, I am not getting desired output. Here is my code, Could you tell me what is going wrong?

```
 public List<List<Integer>> threeSum(int[] nums) {
        
        Set<List<Integer>> res = new HashSet<>();
        
        for(int i = 0; i< nums.length; i++){
            
            int target = 0-nums[i];
            Set<Integer> neg = new HashSet<>();
            
            for(int j = i+1 ; j<nums.length; j++){
                
                int rem = target - nums[j];
                if(neg.contains(nums[j])){
                    res.add(new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(nums[i], rem, nums[j])));
                }
                else{
                    neg.add(rem);
                }
                
            }
        }
        System.out.println(res);
        return new ArrayList<>(res);
        
    }
```

Here my nums is `[-1,0,1,2,-1,-4]`.
My output is `[[-1,2,-1],[0,1,-1],[-1,0,1]]`. Why am I getting both `[0,1,-1]` and `[-1,0,1]` into res as both contain the same elements. I what only one of these? What should I do?

Comment: "Why am I getting both" because they're different. Lists are only equal if they contain the same elements in the same order. If you want to ignore order, sort them.

Comment: Thanks, @AndyTurner, is there any way by which I can check for only elements without order? Is there any other DS that I am missing out on?

Comment: There are other data structures; but do you really need anything more complicated than sorting a list?

Comment: Sorting is adding extra time, I want to solve it in O(n^2)

Comment: Sorting a fixed-length list is an constant-time operation. It has to be, there's no variable.

Comment: now my time complexity becomes O(3n^2). Can I do it in O(n^2)

Comment: There's no difference between `O(3n^2)` and `O(n^2)`. And where does the 3 come from?

Comment: 3 is the fixed length of the List that I am sorting before adding to res.

Comment: It takes more than 3 operations to sort a 3-element list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the Javadoc of [`List.equals`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html#equals-java.lang.Object-):

> Returns true if and only if the specified object is also a list, both lists have the same size, and all corresponding pairs of elements in the two lists are equal.

So, `[0,1,-1]` and `[-1,0,1]` aren't equal, despite containing the same elements, because they aren't in the same order.

The easiest way to solve this would be to sort the list:

```
res.add(Stream.of(nums[i], rem, nums[j]).sorted().collect(toList()));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can sort the `List` before adding to the `Set` so they will be in the same order.

Comment: Correct! I missed the duplicate elements. Edited accordingly.